# Excel: Extract data from a excel matrix

Tags: excel

I have an excel data like a matrix (see screenshot below).

[image]

I would like to know how to extract the data from that table. the result should be the following:

[image]

the result shows the 'role' to which person has (identified by a number).
will appreciate your help.

with best regards

Comment: Is there any meaning to the numbers matching a person to a role?

Comment: No, the number for this use case has no meaning

Comment: what method had u tried/explored sir?